# jQuery pesquisa em uma tabela

Tags: jquery

Estou renderizando valores em uma tabela e tenho que filtrar por um campo que chama razao, para isso utilizo um `script`, a consulta funciona mas ao deletar a consulta feita os valores anteriores não voltam, ou seja ao apagar o campo pesquisa a pesquisa ainda persiste.

HTML pesquisa:

```html
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control pesquisa" style="max-width:200px" />
```

Js:

```js
 $(".pesquisa").keyup(function () {
                var texto = $(this).val();
                $(".lista").css("display", "grid");
                $(".lista").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).find(".razao").text().toUpperCase().indexOf(texto.toUpperCase()) < 0) {
                        $(this).css("display", "none");
                    }
                })
            })
```

HTML lista:

```html
 @if (Model != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr class="lista" data-codigo="@item.codigo" data-razao="@item.razao">
                            <td class="col-sm-2 codigo" ><span>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.codigo)</span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-4 razao">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.razao)
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-2">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cidade)
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-2">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.estado)
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-2">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.telefone)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao apagar o valor do campo de pesquisa, você deve retirar o estilo `display: none`, assim todos os itens irão voltar para o seu estado original, ou seja, irão aparecer novamente.

Do jeito que está sua função, ele apenas esconde os resultados que não são compatíveis com o valor do campo de pesquisa e não faz o contrário, que é mostrar.

Comment: Nossa é mesmo! muito obrigado pela ajuda.. passou despercebido essa hahahaha. Obrigado mesmo!!

Answer (score 0):

Tenho esse script que pode servir ao seu caso.

```
 $('#tblSegundoNivel_linha1 tbody').find('tr').each(function (indexTr, valueTr) {
            $(this).find('td').each(function (indexTd, valueTd) {
                if (indexTd === 5) {
                    if ($(valueTd).html().indexOf(b) === -1) {
                        $(valueTd).parent().hide();
                    } else {
                        $(valueTd).parent().show();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

A pesquisa é feita pelo número da coluna, também preferi esconder os resultados com $().hide() ao meu ver fica mais limpo o código.